# Jest import errors with spfx solutions

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, jestjs, ts-jest, spfx

Can Jest be used effectively with SharePoint Framework solutions that utilize React?. I am encountering import errors in my spfx webparts, the error says the the module cannot be imported.

See below error details -

```
Cannot find module './httpClient/HttpClient' from 'node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js
      src/common/services/sp-services.ts
      src/webparts/TestWebpart/components/custom/Services.ts
      src/webparts/TestWebpart/components/TestWebpart.tsx
      src/webparts/TestWebpart/test/TestWebpart.test.tsx

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js:14:20)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.